# Awk counting occurrences strange behaviour

Tags: bash, unix, awk, unique, xargs

I need to count the number of occurrences of elements of the second column of a large number of files. The script I'm using is this:

```
{
 el[$2]++
}
END {
    for (i in el) {
    print i, el[i] >> "rank.txt"
    }
 }
```

For running it over a large number of files I'm using `find | xargs` this way :

```
find . -name "*.txt" | xargs awk -f script.awk
```

The problems is that if I count the number of lines of the output files `rank.txt` (with a `wc -l rank.txt`) the number I get (for example 7600) is bigger than the number of unique elements of the second row (for example 7300), that I obtain with a :

```
find . -name "*.txt" | xargs awk '{print $2}' | sort | uniq | wc -l
```

In fact giving a :

```
awk '{print $1}' rank.txt | sort | uniq | wc -l
```

I obtain the right number of elements (following the example I'll gett 7300). So it means that the elements of the first column of the output files are not unique. But, this shouldn't happen!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably combination of the fact that the input files (`*.txt`) contain non-unique elements, and the `xargs` functionality.
Remember that **xargs, when there is a large number of files, is called repeatedly** with different set of arguments. This means that in the first example, if there is larger number of files, some of the files are not processed in one awk run, which results in higher number of "unique" elements in the output.

You could try this:

```
find . -name "*.txt" | xargs cat | awk -f script.awk
```

Comment: Oh, I really didn't know this! Right now I cannot test it but I'll let you know if it works. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @TomasT. nice to know the xargs 'feature'. "when there is a large number of files..." can you define the " a large number" please? what's the default value? How can we avoid this to happen? via xargs --max-args=n ? or --max-chars=n ?  thanks

Comment: @Kent, this is limited by max command-line size, so basically there will always be some limit.

Answer (score 0):

YOu can find out where the non-duplicates in $1 are by using

```
find . -name "*.txt" | xargs awk '{print $2}' | sort | uniq -c | awk '$1 > 1 {print}'
```

I don't have a way to test this right now, the intent of last awk is to filter output of `uniq -c` to show only records that have a count greater than one.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! This isn't exactly what I needed but I was looking for something similar too.